# Codec not found for requested operation

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra-driver-core-3.0.0-1 .

In my Table I am having a column `frozen<list<UDT type>>`.

Now while I perform a select operation,
(row.getList("UDTtype",Nov.class),)

I am getting the below exception .

Codec not found for requested operation: `[frozen<keyspace.UDT_Type> <-> com.abc.Nov]`

Please let me know, if I am missing something.

I am using datastax.driver

Comment: I assume you use the datastax driver?

Comment: I know that there was a Bug in the 3.0.0 version where you had to use a workaround in order to register the codecs for your UDT. 

Did you implement a Codec for your UDT at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know that there was a Bug in the 3.0.0 version where you had to use a workaround in order to register the codecs for your UDT. Did you implement a Codec for your UDT at all?

Try to upgrade to 3.1.0 if you already implemented a Codec. If not implement one by following [the guide](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/custom_codecs/).

Answer (score 0):

Add UDT annotation for the UDT class, for which you defined type in the schema. And before query(like select, update, delete) try to map the UDT codecs using Mappingmanager.

`MappingManager manager = new MappingManager(session); manager.udtCodec(Nov.class, KEYSPACE_NAME);`

This is the best way to overcome the Codec not found error.